# Why does passing one date query via Mysql2 from Ruby work but another not?

Tags: mysql, ruby, date, mysql2

EDITED for clarity and added info:

Total newbie to Ruby coding (and coding in general) so please be gentle.

I have a MySQL database, and I want to pull out some data from one of the tables, a column of which is labelled "fulldate".

The following code works to pull out all rows after a certain date.

```
start_date = Date.new(2018, 1, 2)
end_date  = Date.new(2018, 1, 12)

clw_check = client.query('SELECT * FROM rotadates WHERE fulldate >"#{start_date}"')
clw_check.each do |row| puts row["fulldate"] end
```

Then the output is a list of dates from each row.

However, when I change to

```
clw_check = client.query('SELECT * FROM rotadates WHERE fulldate <"#{end_date}"')
clw_check.each do |row| puts row["fulldate"] end
```

then this produces

```
=> []
```

If I put the date instead of the #{} expression, then I get a list of dates with both less than and greater than expressions.

I have searched StackOverflow and the net in general, but cannot for the life of me work out why it works with the first expression the second.

A check on whether start_date and end_date are dates or strings says they are dates, and the MySQL column is also a date with identical yyyy-mm-dd format.

Example of rows from MySQL table:

### rotadates

| idDate | fulldate | year | month | day | quarter | week | dayOfWeek | weekend | clw |
| 20180102 | 2018-01-02 | 2018 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 20180103 | 2018-01-03 | 2018 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 20180104 | 2018-01-04 | 2018 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 0 | 1 |
| 20180105 | 2018-01-05 | 2018 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 0 | 1 |
| 20180106 | 2018-01-06 | 2018 | 1 | 6 | 1 | 1 | 6 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: it's not raising an error but it's just not giving results?  can you show us a few rows from `rotadates`?  Also is `fulldate` a string or a date type in mysql2?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why but when I pass this in IRB it does not seem to work whereas in Aptana console it does.